# Desert Temples have a purpose in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What are the bonuses to a desert pyramid in minecraft? Are they best to be converted into homes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Desert Temples each contain a hidden chamber that is booby-trapped with several blocks of TNT and a Pressure Plate.

In the center of the temple's ground floor is a single block of Blue Wool. Underneath this blue wool is a 'booby-trapped' hidden chamber with four chests that can each contain very valuable loot. The trap consists of a Stone Pressure Plate (located directly under the Blue Wool), connected to a 3x3x1 grid of TNT.
Items in these chests can include Emeralds (rare), Diamonds, Iron Ingots, Gold Ingots, Enchanted Books, Rotten Flesh and Bones.

Answer (score 0):

They have booby traps and treasure, much like jungle temples.